# Detect click in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I having trouble detecting clicks in an iframe(iframe id is `'#ptifrmtgtframe'` and  tag id is `'#CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_CLASS_SRCH'`).  I have tried:

```
$('#ptifrmtgtframe').click( function() {
  $('#CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_CLASS_SRCH').click( function() {

    console.log("clicked");
  });
});
```

I have also tried

```
var htmlDocument = document.querySelector('#ptifrmtgtframe').contentDocument;

$(htmlDocument).contents().find('#CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_CLASS_SRCH').on('click', function() { 
  console.log("clicked");});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iframes are a bit different in that you have to load them and get their contents before you can do anything with it:

```
$('#ptifrmtgtframe').on('load', function() {
  var iframe = $(this).contents();
  iframe.find('#CLASS_SRCH_WRK2_SSR_PB_CLASS_SRCH').click( function() {
    console.log("clicked");
  });
});
```

Comment: I got `a.indexOf is not a function` .  I think there is something weird about this page it has been giving me trouble for the past few days.

Comment: Oh, that was an accident. It should have been `on('load'` not just `.load(`. Updated.

Comment: Awesome! It worked.  I have one last question, if I want to manipulate this iframe, do I just use jquery normally with `iframe` ?  Can I do `$(iframe).find("something")` ?

Comment: You should be able to create a body variable like `var iframeBody = iframe.find("body");` and work with `iframeBody.find()`

Comment: Hey maybe you could check out my new question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44148525/strategy-to-check-for-content-change-in-iframe)